# Python Board Game - "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Tags: python, list, variables, tkinter, typeerror

I'm trying to produce an AI to be used on a game of Connect 4 in Python. The game creates a text version of the board which is used for calculations by AI and game functions.

Implementing a more advanced AI, I'm trying to create an array of rows from the text board as follows:

```
def scorePosition(boardLog, player):
    score = 0
    ## Score Horizontal
    for r in range(boardHeight):
        rowArray = [int(i) for i in list(boardLog[r,:])]
        for c in range(boardWidth - 3):
            window = rowArray[c:c+4]

            if window.count(player[1]) == 4:
                score += 100
            elif window.count(player[1]) == 3 and window.count(0) == 1:
                score += 10
    return score
```

But the line *rowArray = [int(i) for i in list(boardLog[r,:])]* returns the error:
*TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple*

the boardLog asset is created as follows:

```
boardWidth=7
boardHeight=6
boardLog = [boardWidth*[0] for x in range(boardHeight)]
```

I'm aware boardLog isn't a standard list, but I'm not sure how to adapt this code to work with it.

Any ideas? It's driving me nuts!

thanks :)

Comment: `boardLog` IS a standard `list`, and that's exactly the problem - lists don't support multidimensional indexing like you're trying to use, that looks like you've blindly copied some code that relies on `numpy` arrays.

Comment: I haven't copied their code, rather followed a tutorial and adapted it as best I could for my use-case! hope that makes sense

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access element of a list with this syntax.

Here are the 2 solutions you could use:

- If you want to use a list, access it with `rowArray = [int(i) for i in list(boardLog)[r]]`
- If you want no use a numpy array, acces it with `rowArray = [int(i) for i in np.array(boardLog)[r,:]]`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using numpy arrays instead of basic Python lists.
With numpy creating a *m x n* array initialized with zeros can be done with [numpy.zeros](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html):

```
boardWidth=7
boardHeight=6
boardLog = np.zeros((boardWidth, boardHeight))
```

Notice that argument is a tuple instead of two separate values.
From here on out, since `boardLog` is numpy array now, you can use *fancy indexing* to access rows:

```
for r in range(boardHeight):
    rowArray = boardLog[r, :]
```

Or you could just do the following:

```
for rowArray in boardLog:
    # rest of code here
```

Comment: Thanks for this :)